# ngx-bootstrap modal takes a long time (over 1 minute) to open in internet explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Angular: 5.0.2
Bootstrap: 4.0.0
ngx-bootstrap: 2.0.2

Modal works fine in Chrome but hangs in internet explorer 11.

This is the call to modalService from component.ts:

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
template,
Object.assign({}, { backdrop: true }, { class: 'modal-dialog-custom-profile' })
);
```

With html template:

```
<button type="button" class=" fa fa-th-large pickerIcon no-padding-bottom" value="Open Selector" (click)="openModal(template)">
<ng-template #template>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have similar behavior using same same stack also on ngx dropdown up to 9 sexonds to open on ie11... any help?

Comment: I had to reduce the size of my template (DOM) in order to get it to load faster. I changed [hidden] to *ngIf in several places and created a pipe to reduce the number of options returned to my *ngFor. Not ideal but it is acceptable for now...